# Onreadystatechange ajax request fail to equal to 4 and 200

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, networking

My Ajax request has failed. Javascript

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("orderSummary").innerHTML = "success";
                document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("orderSummary").innerHTML = "failure";
```

this js code send a get request to my php file. Now i output text to orderSummary to see where my code fail. Apparently the status did not go 4 and 200 which is success

is that a networking issue or codes. code is very simple so no syntx issue

```
<?php
    include "config.php";   
    $prodid = intval($_GET["prodcat"]; // prod id whether is is skin or fragrance   
    $sql = "SELECT name, detail, price FROM products WHERE type=" . $prodid;   
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);    
    $product_arr = array(); 
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<select>";
        echo "<option>" . $row["name"] . "</option>";    
    }   
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: show us the response in network tab of chrome (for this request)

Comment: I also output the ready state and the status. ready state is 4 put status is 500

Comment: issue is with your server. 500 is internal server error. post the server side code and remove the front end tags, then add the server side lang tags

Comment: how do i get the server side code and what do u mean by that. Running ubuntu lamp stack. basic php settings

Comment: add the php code that handle this request

Comment: not here. edit the question

Comment: Lol i got it, well i think (). Lol yup it works. Is there a way to give u credit for helping me man?

Comment: everyone is here to learn and share brother. I am editing your code a little to format it